# Breakage of a support during rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram

This is a trivial question and probably already asked elsewhere, but not being a native English speaker I struggle to use effective keywords.

In any case, we have a thin homogeneous rod resting on a smooth horizontal plane and free to rotate around its own end which is hinged to a support integral with the plane and free from any sort of friction. At a certain point this support breaks and therefore the rod will rotate and translate in the plane.

Well, my question is whether in these circumstances the momentum, angular momentum and kinetic energy of the rod are conserved, or whether due to the "breaking of the support" one of these quantities will not be conserved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the pivot point breaks, it exerts a force on the rod;  so linear momentum is not conserved.  It can be shown that this force does not exert a torque on the rod (taking the origin to be the pivot point) and therefore angular momentum is conserved.  And since the force acts at a single point (rather than over a distance), it does no work on the rod, and therefore the rod's energy is conserved.

After the pivot point breaks, all three quantities are conserved, since there are no net horizontal forces being exerted.  (Note also that the angular momentum of the rod is conserved about *any* choice of origin, not just the point where the pivot was.)

The values of the three conserved quantites (momentum, angular momentum, and energy) do not change when the pivot breaks;  they have the same values immediately before and immediately after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very clear! So, if energy is conserved:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{mL^2}{3}\omega_i^2 = \frac{1}{2}\frac{mL^2}{12}\omega_f^2 + \frac{1}{2}m\left(\omega_f\frac{L}{2}\right)^2
$$

and if angular momentum is conserved:

$$
\frac{mL^2}{3}\omega_i = \frac{mL^2}{12}\omega_f + m\left(\omega_f\frac{L}{2}\right)\frac{L}{2}
$$

It's right?

Comment: @Monster: The momentum also does not change when the pivot breaks, so you will need to account for that as well.

Comment: So, such an equation?
$$
m\left(\omega_i\frac{L}{2}\right) = m\left(\omega_f\frac{L}{2}\right)
$$
Thanks always for your availability.

Comment: That is in fact true.  And note that this implies that $\omega_i = \omega_f$.